# jQuery - After refreshing the page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, compatibility

At the moment, I am learning how to write in javascript and jquery. However, I wrote a simple jquery code where when you enter the page/website it automatically scrolls to a specific div. The script is working fine when I am loading the page/website and automatically scrolls to the div I want. The problem is coming when I am refreshing the browser. After the refreshed page the script doesn't want to scroll to the div I pointed in the code. If someone could help me I will be really grateful and thank you in advance.

On Chrome and Opera the script is working even after the refresh is made. However, I cannot say the same for Firefox, IE and Edge.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Left_Container").animate({
       scrollTop: $(".Home_Left").offset().top
    }, 0);
});
```

PS: I am using "Left_Container" instead of "HTML,body" because I want only to scroll in that particular div.

Best regards,

George S.

Comment: can you create like a jsbin of this or something?  I don't fully understand your issue.  `$(document).ready()` runs every time a page is refreshed.

Comment: @hvchris Sorry, I missed an important part. The script is working on Chrome and Opera. However, on Firefox, IE and Edge after the refresh button is pushed the script stops working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers will save your scroll position after page reloads so it's not a problem of your code.

What you can do is just force the browser to instantly scroll to top and then animate to your div like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Left_Container").scrollTop(0); // go to the top instantly (no animation)
    $(".Left_Container").animate({ // then animate down
       scrollTop: $(".Home_Left").offset().top
    }, 0);
});
```